# How to compare geocoordinates in a specific radius

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, geolocation, reverse-geocoding

I'm not sure how to word that question, so I apologize for any trouble in understanding. 
I've given Geocoordinates (Lat, Long) and a radius of N kilometers.

We've also given a database with documents containing geocoordinates. 
Now my task is to check if any of those documents' coordinates is within the radius.

I'm not sure how I can check if the coordinates are in the radius or not. I saw that the Google Maps API supports reverse geocoding, but I couldn't really find anything usable.

I hope someone can help to get me in the right direction!

Edit: I'm using MongoDB to store my event documents (contains an array with the lat and long)

Comment: What kind of database do you use? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Thanks! Just did

Comment: If you need geo based operations you can take a look at https://turfjs.org/

Comment: @ŽilvinasJocius Omg that is awesome! Thanks a lot! I'll try it out now